# How do I turn my static Bootstrap Tabs component to work dynamically?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5

Below is a segment of my hard-coded Bootstrap Tabs component

```
<div class="col d-flex justify-content-center col-12 col-md-6">
<div class="mt-5">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
      <a
        class="nav-link ingredients"
        role="tab"
        data-bs-toggle="tab"
        href="#tab-10"
        ><strong>Dough / Sauce / Cheese</strong></a
      >
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
      <a
        class="nav-link active ingredients"
        role="tab"
        data-bs-toggle="tab"
        href="#tab-11"
        ><strong>Toppings</strong></a
      >
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
      <a
        class="nav-link ingredients"
        role="tab"
        data-bs-toggle="tab"
        href="#tab-12"
        ><strong>Extra Flavour Toppings</strong></a
      >
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="tab-10">
      <div>
        <ul
          class="nav nav-tabs d-lg-flex justify-content-center"
          role="tablist"
        >
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
            <a
              class="nav-link active ingredients"
              role="tab"
              data-bs-toggle="tab"
              href="#tab-13"
              ><strong>Dough</strong></a
            >
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
            <a
              class="nav-link ingredients"
              role="tab"
              data-bs-toggle="tab"
              href="#tab-14"
              ><strong>Base Sauce</strong></a
            >
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
            <a
              class="nav-link ingredients"
              role="tab"
              data-bs-toggle="tab"
              href="#tab-15"
              ><strong>Base Cheese</strong></a
            >
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="tab-pane active" role="tabpanel" id="tab-13">
            <div class="row mt-4">
              <div
                class="col flex-column justify-content-md-center col-142 col-md-4 mt-3 d-flex ingredient-border"
              >
                <p
                  class="text-center d-lg-flex justify-content-lg-center fw-bold"
                  style="font-size: 15px"
                >
                  Regular Dough
                </p>
                <img
                  class="img-fluid"
                  src="assets/img/Screenshot%20from%202024-01-22%2021-33-57.png"
                />
              </div>
              <div
                class="col d-md-flex flex-column justify-content-md-center col-142 col-md-4 mt-3"
              >
                <p
                  class="text-center d-lg-flex justify-content-lg-center fw-bold"
                  style="font-size: 15px"
                >
                  Stuffed Crust
                </p>
                <img
                  class="img-fluid"
                  src="assets/img/Screenshot%20from%202024-01-22%2021-54-18.png"
                />
              </div>
              <div
                class="col d-md-flex flex-column justify-content-md-center col-142 col-md-4 mt-3"
              >
                <p
                  class="text-center d-lg-flex justify-content-lg-center fw-bold"
                  style="font-size: 15px"
                >
                  Regular Thin Crust
                </p>
                <img
                  class="img-fluid"
                  src="assets/img/Screenshot%20from%202024-01-22%2021-57-37.png"
                />
              </div>
              <div
                class="col d-md-flex flex-column justify-content-md-center col-142 col-md-4 mt-3"
              >
                <p
                  class="text-center d-lg-flex justify-content-lg-center fw-bold"
                  style="font-size: 15px"
                >
                  Regular Thick Crust
                </p>
                <img
                  class="img-fluid"
                  src="assets/img/Screenshot%20from%202024-01-22%2022-08-52.png"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="tab-14">
            <p>Content for tab 14.</p>
            <div class="row mt-4">
              <div
                class="col flex-column justify-content-md-center ingredient-border col-12 col-md-3 mt-4 d-flex"
              >
                <p
                  class="text-center d-lg-flex justify-content-lg-center fw-bold mb-0"
                  style="font-size: 15px"
                >
                  No Sauce
                </p>
                <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/NS.avif" />
              </div>
              <div
                class="col flex-column justify-content-md-center col-12 col-md-3 mt-4 d-flex"
              >
                <p
                  class="text-center d-lg-flex justify-content-lg-center fw-bold mb-0"
                  style="font-size: 15px"
                >
                  Buffalo Base Sauce
                </p>
                <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/BM.avif" />
              </div>
              <div
                class="col flex-column justify-content-md-center col-12 col-md-3 mt-4 d-flex"
              >
                <p
                  class="text-center d-lg-flex justify-content-lg-center fw-bold mb-0"
                  style="font-size: 15px"
                >
                  Buffalo Chicken Sauce
                </p>
                <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/BP.avif" />
              </div>
              <div
                class="col flex-column justify-content-md-center col-12 col-md-3 mt-4 d-flex"
              >
                <p
                  class="text-center d-lg-flex justify-content-lg-center fw-bold mb-0"
                  style="font-size: 15px"
                >
                  Creamy&nbsp; Garlic Sauce
                </p>
                <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/GS.avif" />
              </div>
              <div
                class="col flex-column justify-content-md-center col-12 col-md-3 mt-4 d-flex"
              >
                <p
                  class="text-center d-lg-flex justify-content-lg-center fw-bold mb-0"
                  style="font-size: 15px"
                >
                  Home-Style Italian Tomato Sauce
                </p>
                <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/SH.avif" />
              </div>
              <div
                class="col flex-column justify-content-md-center col-12 col-md-3 mt-4 d-flex"
              >
                <p
                  class="text-center d-lg-flex justify-content-lg-center fw-bold mb-0"
                  style="font-size: 15px"
                >
                  Hot Honey Sauce
                </p>
                <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/HB.avif" />
              </div>
              <div
                class="col flex-column justify-content-md-center col-12 col-md-3 mt-4 d-flex"
              >
                <p
                  class="text-center d-lg-flex justify-content-lg-center fw-bold mb-0"
                  style="font-size: 15px"
                >
                  Pesto Sauce
                </p>
                <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/SP.avif" />
              </div>
              <div
                class="col flex-column justify-content-md-center col-12 col-md-3 mt-4 d-flex"
              >
                <p
                  class="text-center d-lg-flex justify-content-lg-center fw-bold mb-0"
                  style="font-size: 15px"
                >
                  Smokey Texas Bbq
                </p>
                <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/SQ.avif" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="tab-15">
            <div class="row mt-4">
              <div
                class="col d-lg-flex flex-column justify-content-md-center align-items-lg-center ingredient-border col-12 col-md-3 mt-4 d-flex"
              >
                <p
                  class="text-center d-lg-flex justify-content-lg-center fw-bold mb-0"
                  style="font-size: 15px"
                >
                  No Cheese
                </p>
                <i class="fa fa-hand-stop-o"></i>
              </div>
              <div
                class="col flex-column justify-content-md-center col-12 col-md-3 mt-4 d-flex"
              >
                <p
                  class="text-center d-lg-flex justify-content-lg-center fw-bold mb-0"
                  style="font-size: 15px"
                >
                  Dairy-Free Cheese
                </p>
                <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/ZB.avif" />
              </div>
              <div
                class="col flex-column justify-content-md-center col-12 col-md-3 mt-4 d-flex"
              >
                <p
                  class="text-center d-lg-flex justify-content-lg-center fw-bold mb-0"
                  style="font-size: 15px"
                >
                  Six Cheese Base
                </p>
                <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/XC.avif" />
              </div>
              <div
                class="col flex-column justify-content-md-center col-12 col-md-3 mt-4 d-flex"
              >
                <p
                  class="text-center d-lg-flex justify-content-lg-center fw-bold mb-0"
                  style="font-size: 15px"
                >
                  Mozzarella Cheese
                </p>
                <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/MZ.avif" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

An image of the result of the above code is shown here:
[image]

As shown, the tab: "Dough/Sauce/Cheese" and its sub-tab: "Dough" are selected at start-up because they both have an "active" class assigned to them.

Here I have the modified code to dynamically create the same component.

```
<div class="col d-flex justify-content-center col-12 col-md-6">
  <div class="mt-5">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      <li
        *ngFor="let navItem of ingredients.navItems; index as indx"
        class="nav-item"
        role="presentation"
      >
        <a
          class="nav-link ingredients"
          [ngClass]="{ active: indx === 0 }"
          role="tab"
          data-bs-toggle="tab"
          href="{{ navItem.href }}"
        >
          <strong>{{ navItem.title }}</strong>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div
      *ngFor="let tabcontent of ingredients.tabcontent1"
      class="tab-content tabcontent1"
    >
      <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="{{ tabcontent.id }}">
        <div>
          <ul
            class="nav nav-tabs d-lg-flex justify-content-center"
            role="tablist"
          >
            <li
              *ngFor="let navItem of tabcontent.navItems; index as indx2"
              class="nav-item"
              role="presentation"
            >
              <a
                class="nav-link ingredients"
                [ngClass]="{ 'active show': indx2 === 0 }"
                role="tab"
                data-bs-toggle="tab"
                href="{{ navItem.href }}"
                ><strong>{{ navItem.name }}</strong></a
              >
            </li>
          </ul>
          <div class="tab-content">
            <div
              *ngFor="let panel of tabcontent.tabpanels"
              class="tab-pane"
              role="tabpanel"
              id="{{ panel.id }}"
            >
              <div class="row mt-4">
                <div
                  *ngFor="let ingredient of panel.ingredients"
                  class="col flex-column justify-content-md-center col-142 col-md-4 mt-3 d-flex ingredient-init-border"
                  [ngClass]="{ 'ingredient-selected-border': ingredient.name === selectedIngredient }"
                >
                  <p
                    class="text-center d-lg-flex justify-content-lg-center fw-bold"
                    style="font-size: 15px"
                  >
                    {{ ingredient.name }}
                  </p>
                  <a (click)="setSelectedIngredient(ingredient.name)">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="{{ ingredient.img }}" />
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the initial result produced by the modified code:
[image]

As seen, the "Dough/Sauce/Cheese" tab is highlighted as expected but it's sub-tab, "Dough" is not displayed at startup even though I have set the active class for both of these tabs. I have to click on various tabs to eventually get the state shown in the page for the hardcoded version. How do I ensure both of these tabs are displayed at startup?

Comment: your question is likely to be closed, as there is no reproducible example, not even the first code snippet seems to work.. From the look of it, I'd guess you probably need to move `[ngClass]="{ 'active show': indx2 === 0 }"` on `tab-pane` element instead

Comment: @traynor The code works. It produces the expected result except the active tabs are not automatically displayed at startup as in the case of the hardcoded example. That's the only problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: I tried running the first snippet, and it didn't look like on the screenshots, and angular code is impossible to reproduce without writing complete components and templates with variables methods etc., so without that, it's impossible to say, one can only speculate.. the only thing I noticed is that to show tab, it has to have `tab-pane active` class, which is why I suggested it, and have nothing more to add without something (reasonably) reproducible (stackblitz, for example)